# How to get to FutureTask execution state?

Tags: java, multithreading, futuretask, executors

I have a singleThreadExecutor in order to execute the tasks I submit to it in serial order i.e. one task after another, no parallel execution.

I have runnable which goes something like this

```
MyRunnable implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

When I submit ,for example, three instances of MyRunnable to the afore-mentioned single thread executor, I would expect to have the first task executing and because of the Thread.sleep has Its executing thread in TIMED_WAITING (I may be wrong about the specific state). The other two tasks should not have threads assigned to execute them, at least not until the first task has finished.

So my question is how to get this state via the FutureTask API or somehow get to the thread that is executing the task (if there is no such thread then the task is waiting to be executed or pending) and get Its state or perhaps by some other means?

FutureTask only defines isCanceled() and isDone() methods, but those are not quite enough to describe all the possible execution statuses of the Task.

Comment: the question is: why do you need anything besides isDone()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `getThread()` method to `MyRunnable` that produces the `Thread` executing the `run()` method.

I would suggest adding an instance variable like this (must be [volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java/106787#106787) to ensure correctness):

```
 private volatile Thread myThread;
```

Do this before the `try` block:

```
myThread = Thread.currentThread();
```

And add a `finally` block with this:

```
myThread = null;
```

Then you could call:

```
final Thread theThread = myRunnable.getThread();
if (theThread != null) {
    System.out.println(theThread.getState());
}
```

for some `MyRunnable`.

`null` is an ambiguous result at this point, meaning either, "hasn't run," or "has completed." Simply add a method that tells whether the operation has completed:

```
public boolean isDone() {
    return done;
}
```

Of course, you'll need an instance variable to record this state:

```
private volatile boolean done;
```

And set it to true in the `finally` block (probably before setting the thread to `null`, there's a bit of a race condition there because there are two values capturing the state of one thing. In particular, with this approach you could observe `isDone() == true` and `getThread() != null`. You could mitigate this by having a `lock` object for state transitions and synchronize on it when changing one or both state variables):

```
done = true;
```

Note that there still isn't any guard that prohibits a single `MyRunnable` from being submitted concurrently to two or more threads. I know you say that you're not doing this... today :) Multiple concurrent executions will lead to corrupted state with high likelihood. You could put some mutual exclusive guard (such as simply writing `synchronized` on the `run()` method) at the beginning of the run method to ensure that only a single execution is happening at any given time.

Comment: I like this approach with the Thread.currentThread holding field. However to cover the complete set of states a combination of this and Mark Peters' solution is necessary imho. Because if there is no currentThread assigned to a given runnable this could mean that either the runnable is still pending execution or it has been already executed, so additional flags would be needed like for example hasFinishedExecution. Anyway I mark this as "accepted answer", because Thread's state reflects the actual execution state of a runnable more natively.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the comprehensive example.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap anything you submit to this service in a `Runnable` that records when its run method is entered.

```
public class RecordingRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Runnable actualTask;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    //constructor, etc

    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;
        actualTask.run();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
       return isRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: like any concurrent result isRunning() has no real meaning since checking it is an effective data race. `java.util.concurrent.Future` has `isDone()` that may not flip-flop `false-true-false` and once `true` remains so.

Comment: @best: You could just as easily use a boolean such as `hasStarted` and only record when the run method is entered, or use an `enum` that covers all states.  This example was just for demonstration of the wrapper concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be really thorough, `FutureTask` keeps track of states `READY`, `RUNNING`, `RAN`, and `CANCELLED` internally.  You could create a copy of this class and add an accessor for the state. Then override `AbstractExecutorService.newTaskFor(Runnable)` to wrap it using your `CustomFutureTask` (the inner class is `private`, so just subclassing won't work).

The default implementation of `newTaskFor(Runnable)` is really simple:

```
protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(runnable, value);
}
```

so it wouldn't be a big deal to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Since FutureTask requires a callable object, we will create a simple Callable implementation.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

    public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

        private long waitTime;

        public MyCallable(int timeInMillis){
            this.waitTime=timeInMillis;
        }
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            //return the thread name executing this callable task
            return Thread.currentThread().getName();
        }

    }
```

Here is an example of FutureTask method and it’s showing commonly used methods of FutureTask.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class FutureTaskExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCallable callable1 = new MyCallable(1000);
        MyCallable callable2 = new MyCallable(2000);

        FutureTask<String> futureTask1 = new FutureTask<String>(callable1);
        FutureTask<String> futureTask2 = new FutureTask<String>(callable2);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executor.execute(futureTask1);
        executor.execute(futureTask2);

        while (true) {
            try {
                if(futureTask1.isDone() && futureTask2.isDone()){
                    System.out.println("Done");
                    //shut down executor service
                    executor.shutdown();
                    return;
                }

                if(!futureTask1.isDone()){
                //wait indefinitely for future task to complete
                System.out.println("FutureTask1 output="+futureTask1.get());
                }

                System.out.println("Waiting for FutureTask2 to complete");
                String s = futureTask2.get(200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(s !=null){
                    System.out.println("FutureTask2 output="+s);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(TimeoutException e){
                //do nothing
            }
        }

    }
}
```