# Determining which Callables are currently running in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I'd like to be able to get the Callables that I've [`submit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable))ted to an ExecutorService (specifically a ThreadPoolExecutor) which are currently in progress (so they're not available via `getQueue()`).

I tried creating a subclass to override `beforeExecute`, the but Runnable given there turns out to be a FutureTask, not the original Callable that was submitted.

Is there another way to go about determining the active Callables?

---

Ultimately there's two things I'd like to do with this information:

1. Get the running tasks so they can be displayed in the user interface
2. Check if the file referenced by the Callable matches a pattern, and if so, cancel it

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933219/how-to-get-to-futuretask-execution-state. How precisely do you want to track the state of the tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `AbstractExecutorService.newTaskFor()`, it should give you access to original `Runnable`s and `Callable`s. Then decorate them with your tracking decorator and pass to `super.newTaskFor()`.

Answer (score 1):

as [suggested by axtavt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414953/446591) I created a subclass of `FutureTask`:

```
public class FutureCallable<V> extends FutureTask<V> {
    private Callable<V> callable;

    public FutureCallable(Callable<V> callable) {
        super(callable);
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    public Callable<V> getCallable() {
        return callable;
    }

}
```

and overrode a few methods in my `ThreadPoolExecutor` subclass:

```
public class CustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private Set<FutureCallable<UpdateResult>> running = new HashSet<FutureCallable<UpdateResult>>();

    @Override
    public <T> FutureCallable<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new FutureCallable<T>(callable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        FutureCallable<UpdateResult> task = (FutureCallable<UpdateResult>) r;
        running.add(task);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        FutureCallable<UpdateResult> task = (FutureCallable<UpdateResult>) r;
        running.remove(task);
    }

    ...
}
```